# It is a database? How i can read?

Tags: node.js, database

i want read a database, but i'm not sure that it is a db. I'm programming in node and javascript and in the moment i'm using home bridge and iOS. I want to read a database of a airconditioner to see the energy consumption. So if i send the command:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXwuOXXX" --cert /Users/ac14k_m.pem --insecure -X GET https://192.168.1.21:8888/files/usage.db
```

I download the file named usage.db, the file is this:

`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`

Is this a database? How i can read this? In the AC when i push the button EnergyConsumation I see: 2 or 1 or 0.1 that means the Kw/h

Comment: $ base64 -d <<< U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzAAQAAQEA # output: `SQLite format 3`

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This content is a Base64 encoded SQLite database file, identified by the Base64 decode result of the head of content:

```
$ base64 -d <<< U1FMaXRlIGZvcm1hdCAzAAQAAQEA   # output: SQLite format 3
```

But it is not sure if you have downloaded a Base64 encoded file, or a binary file that was read in Base64. So you may use `| base64 -d` to stream it into a local file to read them, or use a SQLite reader to directly read it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've download SQLite Browser, but when i double click on the file, the Browser ask me a password! SQLChiper encryption -.- i've tried all the password that i've recuperated from the clima and the samsung account. But no result! Do you have another idea?

Comment: @Jackal Are you sure this is the whole content?

Comment: Ops  in the file that i ve copied missing 5,6 lines of text because i can copy here a tot of lines and not all... but in my computer i ve downloaded all the database

Comment: @Jackal Try `base64 -d usage.db > usage_output.db` then use your SQLite browser to open "usage_output.db"

Comment: Ooooooh Yeah! Geno the best! Thank you so much! Now i can implement my App via iOS and Siri! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jackal Pleasure to solve your issue. Please mark it as accepted answer if my answer really helped you, thanks.